# 2 black wires and 2 white wires connected to a light fixture that has one green, one black and one white wire

Tags: electrical

I need some assistance.

I currently am trying to change my track lighting. The track light that it came with has one green, one white and one black wire.

The wires coming out of the ceiling is 2 white and 2 black wires.

How do I know which wires connect to what?

Comment: Where the two white's from the ceiling connected together,  how about the two blacks?

Comment: Yes, the two whites were connected together but the black ones were separate. It is also controlled by a 2 knob light swtich.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the light *and* switch boxes involved please?

Comment: How was the old light fixture wired up?